# Batch to find and replace

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to replace all occurrences of a specific string with a blank space. More precisely, I need a batch file to find all "NaN" in a text file, and replace it with " " (a blank space).
How can I do this?

Bests

CB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can download stuff, you can use [GNU sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) 
example

```
sed -i.bak "s/NaN/ /g" file
```